# Microsoft msdn links for Xbox not working anymore

Tags: xna, msdn, xbox

I'm developing for the Xbox with XNA currently, but when I click on several links to the official Microsoft site, e.g. tutorials and files, then I get redirected to this page:
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/19992.aspx

For example by clicking this link:

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model

Anyone having the same problems with the official Microsoft site currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Microsoft are aware of this issue - although I'm not privy to any information about when/if they will fix it.

Basically, as part of the move to Windows Phone 8, they've separated out the Xbox and Phone development stuff.

If you come across old links like that, you can usually repair them by hand by changing the domain like so:

`forums.create.msdn.com` becomes `xboxforums.create.msdn.com` (change the subdomain)

And

`create.msdn.com` becomes `xbox.create.msdn.com` (add a subdomain)

Comment: Thank you so much, that's the solution.

Comment: @Andrew Russell Is the library diverging or is one of the systems (XBox most likely) being dropped? I find this XBox/WP8 split very odd.

Comment: @ClassicThunder: Not as such. Windows Phone 8 is getting native code, al-a-Metro (or "WinRT" or whatever you want to call it). WP7 and Xbox 360 remain unchanged. I'm *pretty sure* that WP8 will support XNA - but only because it will run old WP7 apps. There is *still* no word from Microsoft about future XNA versions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It'd be like this for a month now. It seems to suggest they are trying to downplay XNA for Windows 8 development which is saddening! You could always use Google's caching service to view the pages if you are finding them from Google... I don't think this will work for downloads though!

Comment: Thank you that's right, I can find the pages with Google's caching. For downloading I had to use Andre Russell's hint.